# Saving data across multiple lines JSON

Tags: php, json, line-breaks

Currently I have PHP and JS save my data in a JSON.

Below is the code for it:

PHP:

```
<?php

$jsonString = file_get_contents('passwords.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$item = $_REQUEST["item"];

// or if you want to change all entries with activity_code "1"
foreach ($data["passwords"] as $key => $password) {
    echo $data["passwords"][$key]['timesToUse'] - 1;
    if ($password['password'] == $q) {

        $data["passwords"][$key]['timesToUse'] = $data["passwords"][$key]['timesToUse'] - 1;
        $data["passwords"][$key]['winningItem'] = $item;
    }
}


$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('passwords.json', $newJsonString);

?>
```

JS:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "passwords.php?q="+passwords[i].password+"&item="+winningItem.getFullName(), true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

The issue that I am having is that initially my JSON file looks like this:

```
{"password":"IS360H","timesToUse":1,"winningItem":""}, 
{"password":"AGRD33","timesToUse":1,"winningItem":""},
{"password":"4BX0FV","timesToUse":1,"winningItem":""}, 
{"password":"99NOTX","timesToUse":1,"winningItem":""}, 
{"password":"X2Z8BO","timesToUse":1,"winningItem":""}, 
{"password":"R9G4Q0","timesToUse":1,"winningItem":""}, 
{"password":"CG9RGT","timesToUse":1,"winningItem":""},
```

As you can see it is nice and neat and is sitting at 1 password per line. However once the file gets modified, it turns to this:

```
{"password":"IS360H","timesToUse":0,"winningItem":"counterUAV"},{"password":"AGRD33","timesToUse":0,"winningItem":"sentryGun"},"password":"4BX0FV","timesToUse":0,"winningItem":"chopperGunner"},"password":"99NOTX","timesToUse":1,"winningItem":""},{"password":"X2Z8BO","timesToUse":1,"winningItem":""}, {"password":"R9G4Q0","timesToUse":1,"winningItem":""},"password":"CG9RGT","timesToUse":1,"winningItem":""},
```

What do I need to do to make my JSON file preserve the line breaks?

Thank you!

Comment: can you paste codes which update your JSON file?

Comment: @RakeshSojitra sorry, just updated!

Comment: @Lovepreet Singh: is right

Comment: @RakeshSojitra as I asked him in the comments of his answer, I will also I ask you: Is there a way for it to be only breaking them up based on each object, not each parameter and value?

Comment: yes, you have to make JSON string first. you can add a new line in file using `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is option `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` available in `json_encode` function, if you are using same for encoding json. Try following:

```
$json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Read more about [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Is there a way for it to be only breaking them up based on each object, not each parameter and value?